# Javascript: how to avoid scientific notation when displaying large unumber

Tags: javascript

Based on http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs131s99/Lessons/03-Out&Data.html, for readability, JavaScript uses scientific notation to display very large numbers (absolute value greater than or equal to 1021). For example, the write statement

```
document.write(1000000000000000000000000);
```

would produce the output 
    1e24

**Can I avoid scientific notation display?**

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format

Answer (score 0):

It’s not for readability. If an integer is larger than 2<sup>53</sup> (9007199254740992), then JavaScript cannot guarantee its exact storage. In your case the number is actually 999999999999999983222784.

Comment: That is correct. I wish I knew scientific notation, because I think it would be pretty easy to expand that. Maybe he'd be OK with inaccurate number storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `YourJS.fullNumber()`.  For instance you could try something like `YourJS.fullNumber(1e20)` to produce `100000000000000000000`.  Try out your own code here:

https://www.yourjs.com/console/?gist=9dce161c033e7391b2f871a19006a653&file=Example+of+YourJS.fullNumber.js