# Javascript convert huge float to string

Tags: javascript, floating-point, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)
>   [Javascript: how to avoid scientific notation when displaying large unumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755195/javascript-how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-when-displaying-large-unumber)

I have this code:

```
var f = 1000000000000000000000; // 1e+21
var fstr = f.toString(); // return "1e+21"
```

But I don't need scientific number representation. I want to get "1000000000000000000000" in 'fstr' variable. How I can get it?

Comment: better answer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can find an util script here:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2206

There is also a short example at the bottom of the page.